# NSInvalidArgumentException: nil is not a valid object ID

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swiftui

My app currently uses a `NavigationLink` to open a view like this:

```
LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout, spacing: 10) {
   ForEach(Array(person.project! as! Set<Project>).sorted { $0.date! > $1.date! }, id: \.self) { (project: Project) in
      NavigationLink(destination: ProjectDetailView(project: project, rootIsActive: self.$isActive)) {
         Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: project.image1 ?? self.projectImage1)! )
    ...
```

However to improve the flow of the UI, I'd like to use a `Sheet` instead of `NavigationLink` to show **ProjectDetailView**

So I changed it like this:

```
LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout, spacing: 10) {
   ForEach(Array(person.project! as! Set<Project>).sorted { $0.date! > $1.date! }, id: \.self) { (project: Project) in
      Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: project.image1 ?? self.projectImage1)! )
         .onTapGesture(count: 1) { sheet = .imageTap(project) }
}
```

where `imageTap` is added to my sheet enum at the top:

```
enum Sheet { case imageTap(Project) }
@State var sheet: Sheet? = nil
```

and my sheet modifier passes the `objectID` of `project` to the view:

```
.sheet(using: $sheet) { sheet in
   switch sheet {
      case .imageTap:
         ProjectDetailView(id: project.objectID, in: viewContext)
```

In my **ProjectDetailView** I've defined my `@ObservedObject` and initialized like this:

```
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject var project: Project
    init(id objectID: NSManagedObjectID, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        if let project = try? context.existingObject(with: objectID) as? Project {
            self.project = project
            self._image1 = State(wrappedValue: project.image1!)
            self._image2 = State(wrappedValue: project.image2 ?? self.image2)
            self._image3 = State(wrappedValue: project.image3 ?? self.image3)
            self._image4 = State(wrappedValue: project.image4 ?? self.image4)
            self._fav = State(wrappedValue: project.favorite)
        } else {
            self.project = Project(context: context)
            try? context.save()
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting the `objectID` to be passed into this view when I invoke the `onTapGesture` on the image. However Xcode errors at this point with
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'nil is not a valid object ID'`

I'm using this same method of passing `objectID` to edit a **Person** entity (my app has two core data entities: **Person** and **Project**), though it doesn't use a `ForEach.` It's just a `.toolbar` button and it works as expected. So I had it print the `person.ObjectID` and it looked like this:
`0x8ae3a33c4ba2adf9 <x-coredata://468DD15D-71D2-4990-BD8B-01CAA9786420/Person/p5>`

So I went and had it print the `project.ObjectID` upon tapping the image, and it prints a similar string that looks valid to me:
`0x8ae3a33c49e2add9 <x-coredata://468DD15D-71D2-4990-BD8B-01CAA9786420/Project/p23>`

So I'm pretty confused as to why **ProjectDetailView** is receiving a `nil` value when printing the `objectID` upon invoking `imageTap` produces a valid looking `objectID`

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure which instance of `project` you're referencing on the line `ProjectDetailView(id: project.objectID, in: viewContext)` or in what scope it exists, but it sure looks like you *should* be using the associated value in the enum that you set when you do `sheet = .imageTap(project)`. In that case, the prior line should be: `case let .imageTap(project):` instead of `case .imageTap:`

Comment: Your init in ProjectDetailView makes very little sense, why are you passing an NSManagedObjectContext to it when you have access to it via the Environment variable and why are you loading the object using objectID when you already know that the object exists in that context? Maybe this isn’t relevant to your issue but you are clearly over complicating things in your code.

Comment: Agh! Thank you @jnpdx that was it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(As discussed in the comments above)*

I'm not sure which instance of project you're referencing on the line `ProjectDetailView(id: project.objectID, in: viewContext)` or in what scope it exists, but instead, you should be using the associated value in the enum that you set when you do `sheet = .imageTap(project)`.

In that case, the prior line should be: `case let .imageTap(project):` instead of `case .imageTap`.